# Why bit shifting?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I was recently looking at a config file that was saving some cryptic values.  I happened to have the source available, so I took a look at what it was doing, and it was saving a bunch of different values and bit shifting them into each other.  It mystified me why someone would do that.  My question, then, is: is there an obvious advantage to storing numeric data in this way?  I can see how it might make for a slightly smaller value to store, byte-wise, but it seems like a lot of work to save a couple of bytes of storage.  It also seems like it would be significantly slower.

The other possibility that occurred to me is that is was used for obfuscation purposes.  is this a common usage of bit shifting?

Comment: obfuscation by bit shifting might be one of the least effective means ever

Comment: @KevinDTimm I once saw a config file that was generated by putting every other character into a separate buffer, and then combining the two. So the file `configParam = true` turned into `cnfgaa  reofiPrm=tr`. Now for a single param, it might look obfuscated enough to not figure out right away. For an entire file to be that way, the pattern was pretty obvious. Only thing, it wasn't just a config file, it was a license file... Mmmhmm... I guess just having it be plain text and enforcing a hash signature was too complex for them...

Comment: Yeah, i also saw a code.
`func SizeVarint(x uint64) int {
 switch {
 case x < 1<<7:
  return 1
 case x < 1<<14:
  return 2
 case x < 1<<21:
  return 3
 case x < 1<<28:
  return 4
 case x < 1<<35:
  return 5
 case x < 1<<42:
  return 6
 case x < 1<<49:
  return 7
 case x < 1<<56:
  return 8
 case x < 1<<63:
  return 9
 }
 return 10
}
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bit shifting seems more common in systems-level languages like C, C++ and assembly, but I've seen it here and there in C# too.  It's not often used so much to save space, though, as it is for one (or both) of two typical reasons:

- You're talking to an existing system (or using an established protocol, or generating a file in a known format) that requires stuff to be very precisely laid out; and/or
- The combination of bits comprise a value that is itself useful for testing.

Anyone who uses it in a high-level language *solely* to save space or obfuscate their code is almost always prematurely optimizing (and/or is an idiot).  The space savings rarely justify the added complexity, and bit shifts really aren't complex enough to stop someone determined to understand your code.

Comment: It seems to me this is the answer: there did not seem to be a justification for the added complexity in the config file.  It was good to hear about the practical uses of bit shifting though.

Comment: You might need it to store for example two `short`s in one `int`eger field in Session state in ASP.net without the overhead of reading out and locking the Session to read two seperate values.  Also the overhead of storing two values in the session is saved.

Comment: @David: And that...is a prime example of where it *shouldn't* be used.  At least til you've profiled and found that your app is too slow entirely because you're reading two session params instead of one.  (PROTIP: unless you're Microsoft, that's highly likely ***not*** to be the case.  Far, *far* more likely is that your algorithm sucks.)

Answer (score 11):

This is one of the common usages of bit shifting. There are several benefit:

1) Bit-shift operations are fast.

2) You can store multiple flags in a single value.

If you have an app that has several features, but you only want certain (configurable) ones enabled, you could do something like:

```
[Flags]
public enum Features
{
    Profile = 1,
    Messaging = 1 << 1,
    Signing = 1 << 2,
    Advanced = 1 << 3
}
```

And your single value to enable Messaging and Advanced would be:

```
(1 << 1) + (1 << 3) = 2 + 16 = 18

<add name="EnabledFeatures" value="18" />
```

And then to figure out if a given feature is enabled, you just perform some simple bitwise math:

```
var AdvancedEnabled = 
    EnabledFeatures & Features.Advanced == Features.Advanced;
```

Comment: I can't imagine it's appreciably faster when collecting a handful of values out of a file though... and the space savings in this sort of application seem insignificant.  Perhaps the developer just went with something s/he was familiar with.

Comment: You can do also wierd And/Or/Xor logic on the value (which usually a state variable) to figure out "merge" states. Really wierd, but I saw it in 3D applicaitons, in rendering kernel, which is only actually solution to keep with complexity of logic and do not pay in performance.

Comment: How is this appreciably different from having an enum with 1,2,4,8,16 etc values?  What does this gain?

Comment: @Jeremy - It's the same thing. Having an enum with those values allows you to use the enum values with bitwise operations.

Comment: Off-the-subject, but watch out for 0 value in [Flags] enum as you won't be able to tell if it's there or not.

Answer (score 4):

I have a project that stores day/hour matrix of available hours during one week.  So it has 24x7 values that have to be stored somehow.

I chose to store it as 7 ints, so each day is represented with one integer, and each hour in it as one bit.  Just an example where it can be useful.

[image]

Comment: Added benefit: `if (available_hours[0] != 0)` says whether you're available at all on Sunday (or Monday, if you're into that).

Comment: Yeah, exactly...  Also with simple AND or OR operations, various overlaps can be calculated in an instant.

Comment: Useful, and informative.  I can see many places I could use this.  However, the way it was used (in a config file) does not seem justified.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes (especially in older Windows programming), there will be information encoded in "high order" and "low order" bits of a value... and it's sometimes necessary to shift to get the information out.  I'm not 100% sure on the reasons behind that, aside from it might make it convenient to return a 64-bit value with two 32-bit values encoded in it (so you can handle it with a single return value from a method call).

I agree with your assertions about needless complexity though, I don't see a lot of applications outside of really heavy number-crunching/cryptography stuff where this would be *necessary*.